# how to configure or edit wp-filebase plugin edit to show author of files

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show the author of the uploaded file. however, at this moment it shows
File Name, Hits and Size.

I use following wordpress plugin.

```
/*
Plugin Name: WP-Filebase
Plugin URI: http://fabi.me/wordpress-plugins/wp-filebase-file-download-manager/
Description: Adds a powerful downloads manager supporting file categories, download counter, widgets, sorted file lists and more to your WordPress blog.
Author: Fabian Schlieper
Version: 0.2.9.34
Author URI: http://wpfilebase.com/
*/
```

Can we do this without touching the code? I mean configuring from backend or do I need to change the code?

Answer (score 0):

yes we can configure the plugin without touching the code.

However, following link was very helpful to me.

[documentation for the templates](http://wpfilebase.com/documentation/templates/)